# Can I use Time Machine for multiple different backups?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, time-machine, external-disk

I have my Macintosh HD 500 Gb who backs up on two external hard drives (both 500 GB), so i have always two backups! But i have an other external hard drive (1TB) with a lot of footage on it which i want to backe up on a new external drive (1TB)!
It is possible to setup Time machine to do this automatically for me, also two different backups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TM can only run one backup scheme. You can include the other external drive to backup to the existing TM backup drive or drives along with your Mac HD drive. Or you can back up all drives to the new 1TB drive (or drives if you want to add others). The 500 Gig drives are not big enough to backup all drives too.

What you might consider is using CCC or SuperDuper to backup the other drive to the new 1TB drive.

SOLUTION by Glenn Leblanc on Apple Communities